# how do I toggle between modes in linux less

Tags: linux

After typing this command

```
less +F file_name.data
```

I am able to see a file as data is being written to on the fly.  This is great but after the data has been fed to the file, I would like to search around the file without leaving the file.  Even after all the data has been written to it, it still says at the bottom of the screen "Waiting for data...(interrupt to abort)".

the phrase "Interrupt", to me, means CTRL+C or CTRL+Z but that is not right since I think it will take me out of the file complete.  Instead, I think I need to just toggle between modes without leaving the editor.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Normally `CTRL-C` is trapped by `less` so that actually you don't quit from less but rather return to the "standard mode". If you don't like this behavior you can run less with `-K` option in which case less will exit after `CTRL-C`. By the way, please note that instead of run `less +F file` you can just hit `F` in "normal mode".

So to answer your question: you toggle between modes by pressing `F` and `CTRL-C`.